# MySQL + Express.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

I'm building API interface based on express.js and it will receive data from MySQL database. Now I was wondering which is best way to open connection to database. Solution A) Open connection at api server startup and end it only when I shut down api server or B) Opening connection to MySQL on every request and after data receive ending it? Tell me pros and cons of each solution and also your own solutions based on similar situations. And yes node is quite new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use connection pool manager so 1) you don't pay the price of opening/closing connection on each request 2) you don't do as much manually to manage connection lifecycle in case of any error

```
// put this in a code path that runs at startup of your server. No actual connection performed
const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

// put this where you need your db data
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```